# Air gap at the top of my HTML page, can't figure out why

Tags: html, css

I've got the following HTML that's styled with CSS. Here is the top of my HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>A Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1 id="header_text">Welcome</h1>
        </div>
```

The gap is between the top of the page and the "header" div.

The CSS that styles this code is

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body{
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    font-size: normal;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#header{
    background: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

Can anyone see the reason for the air gap? I've been working with this for almost a freaking hour and it's driving me insane!

Thanks

Comment: Try setting the background color of the div to check where the gap is: before the div or inside it

Comment: Can you show the rules for '#header_text' as well?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YA57n/ Seems okay.

Comment: Ya, post #header_text info as well please

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using WordPress, based on what you've posted, but WordPress adds a 27px margin-top to `body` (or it might be `html` - I don't remember which) inline when you're logged in as an admin.

Answer (score 0):

Try with margin:0; padding:0; on your header_text. Using a reset?

Comment: Yeah, this was my first thought. OP, have a look at [these](http://www.cssreset.com/), if you aren't already using one. HTML5 Boilerplate is using normalize.css these days, but I've been using the HTML5 Doctor's variant since HTML5 Boilerplate introduced me to it, way back when, and haven't had any issues with it.